# Write delimited strings from an infile to an outfile

Tags: python, string, slice, file-io

The purpose is to search an infile (html) and reproduce the URLs of any images in an outfile which could be passed to wget. This would be the first useful thing I've written in Python and it appears to work well on Fedora. I couldn't find anything specifically like this anywhere. Does anyone have suggestions for improving on this?

```
import fileinput
import re
#replace 'output.txt' with the name of your outfile
file = open('output.txt', 'w')

#prefix and postfix are how we discriminate your substring from the infile's line
prefix = '<img src='
postfix = '.jpg'

#read through the infile line-by-line
for line in fileinput.input():
    if re.search(prefix, line):
        #from if above, if you find the prefix, assign the integer to first_index
        first_index = line.index(prefix)
            if re.search(postfix, line):
                #same as comment above, but for postfix
                second_index = line.index(postfix)
                #write your string plus an newline to the outfile
                file.write(line[first_index+prefix.__len__():second_index+postfix.__len__()]+'\n')
```

Comment: Would that be trying to parse HTML with regex that I smell?

Comment: `wget -prl1 --accept=jpg <url>`

Comment: I do love wget but it always gets more than I asked for. Wget also often complains about some urls and refuses to do the work. It's still always my first go-to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something like this in the past and it worked pretty well... I'm sure it will be more accurate than trying to parse with regex.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class ImageFinder(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.file = open('output.txt', 'w') 
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "img":
            url = [u[1] for u in attrs if u[0] == "src"][0]
            self.file.write(url+"\n")
    def __exit__(self):
        self.file.close()

inputdata = open("myfile.txt").read()
parser = ImageFinder()
parser.feed(inputdata)
```

Comment: Ah, much cleaner solution!